# How should I plan my vacation and work to the USA as a French?

Tags: working-visas, working, french-citizens, working-holiday-visas

Currently working as a Software Developer in France (I'm French), I plan to visit the USA as a tourist first. But then, I'd like to work there, to improve my English skill and diversify my working experiences.

I didn't define the duration yet. I could work for 3 months as well as for 2 years, depending of how good I feel there and the opportunities I get.
But I'd like to be there as a tourist for at least one month and up to three months I guess (then I'll need to earn money to stay confortable enough without using too much of my savings).

I've seen in others questions that modest people tend to get their visa refused because the immigration service is "afraid" that they won't go back to their country.

I'm currently earning between 2600 and 2700€ per month. Moreover, finding a job here in France is quite easy in software development.

The problem is, I feel overwhelmed by informations I can find on the web on how to work in the USA. And I have no clue how should I plan this, to be able to relax and visit the USA before working there.

I'm not asking how to find a job, even though I'd gladly read some advices about it, but how should I manage all this. I don't know where to start and how should I plan this. 
Go to the USA and seek for a job there while visiting ? Or maybe look for a job from France and try to define a start date (if I can find a job) allowing me to come to the USA sooner and visit before starting to work ?
Maybe should I start by working in Canada first ? As it is quite easier as a French to work there. I don't know.

What "scares" me the most is the time required to get this working visa.

In case this information could help answer me, I'm turning 26 this year and I'd like to leave France early 2020.

I first posted this question on the wrong SE site (travel) and apparently it takes at least 18 months to get a working visa. Is there a way to reduce this required time? Or maybe is it possible to work in Canada while applying for a US working visa ?

Bonus : If I could visit Mexico/Cuba/Canada from the USA (a weekend here, a week there..) it would be a BIG plus. During my visit as a tourist or as a worker I don't really mind. (Even though I guess it'll be easier as a tourist)

EDIT : During my searches, I discovered that maybe it could be a nice idea to find a remote job while visiting the US but I'd consider this as a last resort as I am more interested in integrating a US company to improve my English "face to face" in a professional environment.

Thanks.

Comment: [Related question and answer](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/10967/working-in-usa-for-a-usa-company-temporary-without-a-green-card).

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out